# What's the fastest way to synchronize a PostgreSQL with SQLite in Objective C?

Tags: php, objective-c, json, sqlite, postgresql

Facts:

1. We have an iOS app that **pulls all the products from a Postgres** database (main DB) and stores them locally (SQLite)
2. We use these products to do local transactions and once the order is ready, we send the products back to the main DB to register the order through a PHP file that inserts
3. Every time the user logs in for the first time, the app needs to update the products to check price changes, name changes and inventory. **We are using JSON**.
4. We have over 700 products and it takes a long time to do this. We are looking for alternatives to improve speed.

**What we need to do:**

1. The most important thing would be to optimize the app for speed and use minimum server resources. Right now we only have 700 products and 10 apps pulling from it. We want to prepare when we reach 20,000 products and 50 apps pulling from it.
2. Make the app faster and only check the products that have changed prices or names and updates those products on the local database. We know there are some options here like load balancing and query partitioning but we don't know what's the best and fastest way to go since we are pulling from Postgres and inserting into a local SQLite and how big the SQLite can go.
3. Every time we log a user out, we need to pull his open orders from the database. Should we store the entire info of orders on all devices or should we pull each user's with JSON every time they log in?
4. We currently have our server on the internet. We know speeds would improve if we move the server locally but on the long run that is more expensive. Any thoughts?

Any help, specially on database optimization will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you storing all of the products locally, instead of retrieving them from the server as needed?

Comment: Because we don't want to depend on internet connections when taking an order, so whenever we write to the main DB we ask if there's internet connection first to send the info.